# Find the minimum value of $~\cos(x)~$,if $\cos(x) + \cos(y) +\cos(z)=1$ and $\sin(x) + \sin(y)+\sin(z)=1$ for x,y,z being real numbers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have tried to square both the equations, and I got $\sum_{cyc} cos(x)cos(y)+\sum_{cyc}\sin(x)\sin(y)=1$, here $\sum_{cyc}$ means the cyclic sum in x,y,z.Which when further expanded, i got  $\cos(x-y)+\cos(y-z)+\cos(z-x)=1$

Comment: Hint: Try complex numbers.

Comment: without calculus, you could square both equations and add... maybe

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true [...], it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts. – From [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Comment: @insipidintegrator could you elaborate on what exactly i would be doing with complex numbers? i could see that you are essentially using points which are at an angle x,y,and z from the origin

Comment: hi with squaring and adding, is giving me a cyclic equation in x,y,z, but i dont know how to proceed after that.

Comment: Go ahead and show what you get by squaring and adding by editing your original question. Remember that sin^2 + cos^2 = 1 when we use real numbers

Comment: I get $\sum_{cyc} \cos(x)\cos(y) + \sum_{cyc} \sin(x) \sin(y)=1$, what do you do after this?

Comment: OK, please edit your original question, and I'm not sure what cyc means here, sorry. However, the double angle identities may help

Comment: ok i did so! i get $\cos(x-y)+\cos(y-z)+\cos(z-x)=1$

Comment: I'm just guessing here, btw -- using the difference identities, can you isolate cos(x)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138004/discussion-between-barrycarter-and-makhi1249).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\cos x+\cos y+\cos z=1$

$i(\sin x +\sin y + \sin z)=i(1)$

Add the equations.

$e^{xi}+e^{yi}+e^{zi}=1+i$

Represent this equation on an Argand diagram.

[image]

The question asks you for the minimum value of $\cos{x}$, so we make $x$ as close to $\pi$ as possible. This means the top two line segments will become colinear.

[image]

Now we just need to calculate $\cos{x}$. Draw a line segment from $0$ to $1+\text{i}$ to make a triangle. Call the bottom angle of the triangle $\theta$.

[image]

Cosine rule: $\cos{\theta}=\dfrac{1^2+\sqrt{2}^2-2^2}{2(1)(\sqrt{2})}=-\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$

$\cos{x}=\cos{\left(\theta+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)}=\cos{\theta}\cos{(\frac{\pi}{4})}-\sin{\theta}\sin{(\frac{\pi}{4})}=-\dfrac{1+\sqrt{7}}{4}$

Comment: This is a pre-calculus question. I doubt they intended a solution involving the Argand diagram :)

Comment: @barrycarter The OP suggested that they are familiar with the Argand diagram (in the comment "could you elaborate on what exactly i would be doing with complex numbers? i could see that you are essentially using points which are at an angle x,y,and z from the origin").

Comment: hi! is it okay if i ask you for the diagram? i don't understand what you mean by kink, is it like the head of the vector which you mean? Also for minimization, why would the second and third line segment be collinear?

Comment: @makhi1249 I have added diagrams and more explanations.

Comment: thank you for your effort, i understood it.

Comment: Nice solution -- but no complex numbers are needed.  Just consider the points $(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ for $t\in\{x,y,z\}$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Good point. (But for the more general question, "Given $\cos{x}+\cos{y}+\cos{z}=a$ and $\sin{x}+\sin{y}+\sin{z}=b$, find the minimum value of $\cos{x}$" I would say that the complex numbers approach would be easier, unless I'm missing something.)